# Removing desktop icons

Tags: icons, desktop-icons, tweak

In Ubuntu 14.04 Unity places Computer, Home and Trash icons on the desktop. I've tried using Unity-Tweak to remove them but they're still there. How can I remove them?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Run this command from a terminal:
`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false`

Or to do it with GUI open `dconf-editor` and go to org -> gnome -> desktop -> background and uncheck "show-desktop-icons."

Comment: Neither method worked; icons are still there even after a reboot.

Comment: You can try if disabling them individually works e.g.: `gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.desktop trash-icon-visible false`

Comment: Do you have nemo installed? Then try: `gsettings set org.nemo.desktop trash-icon-visible false`

Comment: nemo was the problem; your method worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting cursor over the item you want to move and right click , I think you will get a unpin from desktop option or it may drag down to rubbish bin if you click hold and drag.

Comment: That doesn't work in 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the tips on the web, but none of them worked, so I did a very rudimentary thing as follows, and it worked.  You can remove the "Install Ubuntu" icon permanently, but I just hid it as follows so that I can launch the installer when I really need to install Ubuntu on the main hard disk:

1. Open the terminal.
2. `sudo mkdir /usr/share/applications/UNWANTED_LAUNCHERS`
3. `sudo mv /usr/share/applications/ubiquity.desktop /usr/share/applications/UNWANTED_LAUNCHERS/`

(*Note: The visible file name, "Install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS" with spaces in it does not work for the terminal.  You must use the real file name, "ubiquity.desktop", which Ubuntu actually find it by.)

Comment: Your answer seems disjointed please restructure it so you can deliver your solution to the question better.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install "Tweaks" `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`.
2. Open "Tweaks" > "Extensions" > "Desktop Icons" > Click gear symbol > Disable "Show the personal folder in the desktop" & "Show the trash icon in the desktop".

[image: Ubuntu Tweaks disable desktop icons]

Comment: Hello. Are you sure Gnome Tweaks existed over 7 years ago?

Comment: Probably not, but its one of the 1. results so everyone ends up here...